# I am trying to add a transparent overlay over a div containing material, how do i do this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The transparent overlay is to be of a grayish nature and is supposed to contain a progress bar that blocks use of the div it's covering in the browser until the progress bar is complete. I also wish to do this without the use of flash. How would I do this?

```
 div.transparent_lists
{
 clear:both;
 border-top-style:solid;
 border-bottom-style:solid;
 opacity:0.6;
 filter:alpha(opacity=60);
 border-bottom-color: #A9A9A9;
 border-top-color: #A9A9A9;
 border-bottom-width: thin;
 border-top-width: thin;
 z-index: 1000;
 display: block;
 height: 20px;
 position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
<div id="parent" style="position:relative;height:200px;width:200px;overflow:hidden;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam
    <div id="overlay" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:200px;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;opacity:.8;padding-top:90px;text-align:center;">
        Content for overlay here
    </div>
</div>
```

And you could hide/show the overlay element as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Set that parent to `position: relative` and the transparent child to `position: absolute`:

```
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

div div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/bookcasey/pen/sfruy)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jquery UI progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#animated) and [blockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) together to achieve an overlay with a progress bar.  Here's a quick and dirty example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bb2qh/).

Answer (score 0):

How you would implement it depends on what it is you are loading and how, but...

If it were me, I'd make use of CSS transitions and progress events (assuming it's AJAX) to determine the size of the progress bar.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest